# Boto3 Filter out ACM response to find particular certificate ARN

Tags: python, boto3, aws-certificate-manager

I'm writing a Lambda to lookup the expiry of a certificate in ACM (It's imported so won't auto-renew)

I can pull down the full list of certs in ACM fine, but what I need to do is to get the ARN of a certificate that matches a particular domain name. The response dict has both but I want to be able to filter the response dict to only show the domain name and ARN of the entry matching a given domain name.

I have written a function as below:

```
 def list_certs(self):
    try:
      response = client.list_certificates(
      CertificateStatuses=[
          'ISSUED',
      ],
    )
      print(json.dumps(response["CertificateSummaryList"], indent=4))
      certs = jmespath.search("CertificateSummaryList[?DomainName == '*.example.com'] | [?DomainName == '*.example.com'].stringValue",response)

      print(certs)
      return response
    except ClientError as err:
      print(err)
    else:
      print("Something Possibly wrong")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, this works for me:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import json
import jmespath
acm_client = boto3.client('acm')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event["domain"]
    print("Domain is ", message)
    acm_response = acm_client.list_certificates()
    # Creating JSON from JSONlike structure, prelacing single quotes with double
    acm_as_string = str(acm_response).replace("'", '"')
    # Now we can use it as JSON
    acm_as_json = json.loads(acm_as_string)
    # Find certificate matching the domain
    cert_search_as_list = jmespath.search(f"CertificateSummaryList[?contains(DomainName,`{message}`)]", acm_as_json)
    print("cert is ", cert_search_as_list)
    # Same manipulation of JSONlike structure
    cert_result_as_str = str(cert_search_as_list).strip('[]').replace("'", '"')
    cert_json = json.loads(cert_result_as_str)
    if "CertificateArn" in cert_json:
        certArn = cert_json["CertificateArn"]
        print("certArn is", certArn)
```

We are renewing certs from SNS notification in the form of json message:

```
{ "domain": "something.net" }
```

So, substitute message with your own domain name

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancier version that has dynamic profile and domain prompts:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import json
import logging
import sys
from abc import ABC
from functools import cached_property
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from typing import Optional

import boto3
from prompt_toolkit import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
LOG_FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"


class BaseAwsWrapper(ABC):
    def __init__(self, profile_name: Optional[str] = None):
        self._profile_name = profile_name

        if not self.is_logged_in():
            print("Please log in to AWS cli")
            sys.exit(1)

    def cli_execute(self, command):
        with Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as process:
            output, err = process.communicate(
                b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin"
            )
            if err:
                print(err.decode("utf-8"))

        return output.decode("utf-8")

    def aws_cli_execute(self, command):
        command.insert(0, "aws")
        return self.cli_execute(command)

    def _prompt(self, name: str, available: list[str]) -> str:
        """Generic reusable user input prompt."""
        if len(available) == 1:
            return available[0]

        completer = WordCompleter(available)
        return prompt(f"{name} was not passed, choose a {name}: ", completer=completer)

    @cached_property
    def profile_name(self):
        if not self._profile_name:
            self._profile_name = self.profile_prompt()
        return self._profile_name

    @cached_property
    def available_profiles(self) -> list[str]:
        return self.aws_cli_execute(["configure", "list-profiles"]).split("\n")

    def profile_prompt(self) -> str:
        return self._prompt("profile", self.available_profiles)

    @cached_property
    def session(self):
        return boto3.Session(profile_name=self.profile_name)

    @cached_property
    def identity(self) -> dict:
        if identity := self.aws_cli_execute(["sts", "get-caller-identity"]):
            return json.loads(identity)
        return {}

    @cached_property
    def config_identity(self):
        return self.aws_cli_execute(["configure", "list"]).split("\n")

    def is_logged_in(self) -> bool:
        """
        Check to see if the user is logged in to AWS
        """
        return bool(self.identity)

    def get_account_id(self) -> bool:
        return self.identity.get("Account")

    @cached_property
    def region(self) -> str:
        ident = self.config_identity
        region_line = [x for x in ident if "region" in x][0]
        return region_line.split()[1]


class AwsAcm(BaseAwsWrapper):
    def __init__(
        self,
        profile_name: Optional[str] = None,
        certificate_domain: Optional[str] = None,
    ):
        super().__init__(profile_name)

        self._certificate_domain = certificate_domain

    @cached_property
    def acm(self):
        return self.session.client("acm", region_name=self.region)

    @cached_property
    def available_certificate_arns(self) -> dict[str:str]:
        y = self.acm.list_certificates()
        return {
            x["DomainName"]: x["CertificateArn"] for x in y["CertificateSummaryList"]
        }

    def certificate_prompt(self):
        return self._prompt("certificate", self.available_certificate_arns.keys())

    @cached_property
    def certificate_domain(self):
        if not self._certificate_domain:
            self._certificate_domain = self.certificate_prompt()
        return self._certificate_domain

    @cached_property
    def certificate_arn(self):
        return self.available_certificate_arns.get(self.certificate_domain)


def parse_args():
    """
    Extract the CLI arguments from argparse
    """
    _parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Exec into a fargate container")

    _parser.add_argument("-p", "--profile", help="AWS profile name", required=False)
    _parser.add_argument("-c", "--domain", help="Certificate domain", required=False)

    return _parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    acm = AwsAcm(
        profile_name=args.profile,
        certificate_domain=args.domain,
    )
    print(acm.certificate_arn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```